# Sass mixin with class name as variable and :lang()

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

i am trying create mixin. Something like this

```
 @mixin localesRule($class, $cssProp, $value) {
        .#{$class:lang(pt)}, //...other locales { 
            $cssProp: $value;
        }
    }
```

But got error... Can someone help me? It is possible to do this?

Comment: What is your expected output from the mixin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@mixin localesRule($class, $cssProp, $value) {
  #{$class}:lang(pt), #{$class}:lang(pl), #{$class}:lang(sk), #{$class}:lang(mx), #{$class}:lang(pt-BR) {
    #{$cssProp}: $value;
  }
}

.foo {
  &-button {
    @include localesRule('&', padding-right, 0);
  }
}
```

output:

```
.foo-button:lang(pt), .foo-button:lang(pl), .foo-button:lang(sk), .foo-button:lang(mx), .foo-button:lang(pt-BR) {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: ` @mixin localesRule($class, $cssProp, $value) {
  .#{$class}:lang(pt), .#{$class}:lang(pl), .#{$class}:lang(sk), .#{$class}:lang(mx), .#{$class}:lang(pt-BR) {
    #{$cssProp}: $value;
  }
}`
and then : 
 `&-button {
            font-size: 12px;
          other rules...
            /*&:lang(pt), &:lang(pl), &:lang(br), &:lang(sk), &:lang(mx), &:lang(pt-BR) {
                padding-right: 0;
            }*/
            @include localesRule(&, padding-right, 0);
    
        }`

and no output :|

Comment: look at it now - this is what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you exactly expect, here are a few basic examples in **SCSS**. Let's assume you have a class like this.

```
.login {}
```

Now create a mixin you want to use in the class.

```
@mixin main-button($parent-selector, $property, $selector, $size-value) {
    #{$parent-selector}__img {
        width: 100px;
        #{$property}: left;
    }

    #{$selector} {
        background: none;
    }

    &__button {
        font-size: $size-value;
    };
}
```

Use the mixin in the class.

```
.login {
    @include main-button(&, float, "text", 14px);
}
```

The output should be like this.

```css
.login {
    .login__img {
        width: 100px;
        float: left;
    }

    .text {
        background: none;
    }

    .login__button {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```